# How can I search for a file in just one specific folder in VSCode when using a workspace with multiple folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the workspace feature of VSCode, with two projects, but it's annoying to search for a file in the front-end project and need to pass by back-end files to find the one I want.

I'm using `ctrl + p` to search for files.

How can I search for a file in just one folder with multiple projects opened in the workspace?

Comment: To search for a file within a folder you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.  Then type the`folderName` followed by a slash: either `\` or `/` and you will limit the search to within that folder.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_31.md#new-tree-widget for searching for a folder or a file in the explorer specifically.

Comment: And the fuzzy searching for files will even do this: you probably don't need to enter much of your folderName.  For instance, if you are searching in the `test` folder for a file called `jest.js` then enter `t/j` might be enough to find it.  You do NOT need the enter the entire folderName before the slash.  Pretty sweet.

Comment: @Mark The link you shared is the answer for now, that way I can search for files inside the folder I'm in. Do you want to make a answer with that? that way I can give you the correct answer flag.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe, but the comments and answers are really duplicates of previous questions so I will pass on posting an answer here.  See, e.g.,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508281/how-to-navigate-with-vs-code-explorer/56511584#56511584

Comment: @FelipeAugusto the accepted answer does not match the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that's possible: use a relative path: `./mySearchedProjectName` in "files to include"-input

from [HERE!](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)

[image]

Comment: This is "search in files", not "search for a file" (what the question is asking). I don't know why the OP accepted this as answer. There is no "files to include" input when searching for a file.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED answer to [UPDATED question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57524252/2)**

The fuzzy file finder (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) *somehow* supports prefixing the filename with a folder, such as *folder/filename* to locate a file from a specific folder:

[image: fuzzy search]

But, in my experience, the search is a bit lacking. For example, I find it *usually* can only find files this way if that file has been recently opened in your workspace. It also does not support regex.

The best thing that can be done is to enable including recently opened files by adding this to the workspace settings:

```
"settings": {
    "search.quickOpen.includeHistory": true,
```

AFAIK, there is no other built-in way to filter the results. There are (still) open feature requests for this, like this [Allow quick open to filter on folder names by typing folder name after the file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30404). You can thumbs-up them to hopefully get them noticed.

**ORIGINAL answer to [ORIGINAL question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57524252/1)**

I don't know what you mean by "*projects*" since VS Code only has "*workspaces*" and "*folders*", such that you add *folders* to a *workspace*. I think you're already doing this, where each *folder* contains a separate set of codes.

With that said, the **Search**/**Find** panel has an area to specify **files to include**, where you can limit your search to a specific *folder*. For example:

[image: vscode screenshot 1]

Here I have 3 folders (proj 1-3) added to a workspace. I have 3 sample files with the same text.

[image: vscode screenshot 2]

When searching, you can set **files to include** to a specific folder (*./proj2*), so that the search results will be limited to that folder.

Comment: Yes, I meant folders, and I also meant search for files and not for words inside files, do you know how to do that?

Comment: "For example, I find it usually can only find files this way if that file has been recently opened in your workspace. It also does not support regex and it can't find the file buried in subfolders."  Fuzzy searching in the quickOpen panel does not support regex but I have never had the other problems you indicate.  It always finds files in subfolders and it doesn't matter if they have been recently opened.

Comment: I think he meant when searching using the folder name, like `project/file_name`, when I try to search like this I just see one recently opened file, I can't search though all the files in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best solution to this for me (though it's still a sub-optimal one) is simply to run multiple VS Code instances, one for each folder.

It's a pain to start up, but once you get things going (and hopefully you're not restarting often on your dev machine, so this is less of an issue) it works perfectly: you can search for files with *only* the relevant ones showing up.

Also, if you want to reduce the start-up pain you can make a shortcut/alias/etc. in your operating system that starts both at once.

Comment: I'm using this with one observation: i'm using Ubuntu workspaces (also available on Win), so it's easier to switch between the instances of VSCode (ctrl + tab + up/down)

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint, but yes I also find multiple workspaces help :)